# Python 3: AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola estoy intentando hacer un programa muy simple que cree los datos de un rectángulo y encuentre su centro:

```
class Rectangulo:
    pass
def encuentra_centro(box):
    p = Rectangulo()
    p.x = box.esquina.x + box.anchura / 2.0
    p.y = box.esquina.y + box.altura / 2.0
    return p
 def Nuevo_Rectangulo(an, al, x, y):
    rect = Rectangulo()
    rect.anchura = an
    rect.altura = al
    rect.esquina.x = x
    rect.esquina.y = y
    return rect
 caja = Nuevo_Rectangulo(200.0, 100.0, 4.0, 5.0)
 x = encuentra_centro(caja)
```

Pero cuando ejecuto este script me lanza el siguiente error:

```
AttributeError: 'Rectangulo' object has no attribute 'esquina'
```

¿Alguien sabe qué paso y cómo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te lanza este error por que en efecto tu objeto Rectangulo no tiene ningun atributo 'esquina', esto es por que tu clase no esta implementada de forma correcta.

La forma correcta de implementar tu clase rectangulo seria la siguiente:

```
class Rectangulo(object):
    def __init__(self, an, al, x, y):
        self.an = an
        self.al = al
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def encuentra_centro(self):
        return(((self.x + self.an)/2), ((self.y + self.al)/2))

rect = Rectangulo(200.0, 100.0, 4.0, 5.0)
print(rect.encuentra_centro())
```

Cuando creas una clase lo primero que tienes que hacer es pasarle "**object**" como argumento *(Al hacer esto estas creando una sub-clase de object, todas las clases son "sub-clases" de object pero no voy a entrar en este tema por que no es relevante y puedes googlearlo)*.

Lo siguiente es usar el metodo `__init__(self):`, este metodo es lo primero que se ejecuta al instanciar una clase y aqui es donde se ponen los argumentos que se deben pasar a la clase para que esta se pueda instanciar.

El primer parametro siempre debe de ser "**self**" *(puede ser la palabra que quieras pero self es la que se usa comunmente)*, seguido por los argumentos que escojas.

Para poder acceder a estos argumentos desde dentro de la clase hay que definirlos de la siguiente manera `self.argumento = argumento` (comunmente estas nuevas variables se nombran igual que el argumento que les estas asignando, pero puedes ponerles el nombre que prefieras)

Ya que definiste tus variables en **__init__** puedes definir los metodos de tu clase los metodos se definen como cualquier función pero siempre tienes que pasarles el argumento **self** y si pasas mas de un argumento **self** siempre debe ser el primero.

Esa es la forma correcta de implementar una clase.

Para instanciar una clase y poder usarla hay que asignarla a una variable `rect = Rectangulo(200.0, 100.0, 4.0, 5.0)`, cuando se instancia una clase no hay que pasarle el argumento **self** solo los que tu hayas definido.

Los metodos de las clases se usan con la ***"notacion de punto"*** `clase.metodo()` en donde clase es la instancia de una clase `rect.encuentra_centro()`

Esta explicación es en extremo basica y no cubre mas que la superficie del tema de las clases y la programación orientada a objetos.
Te recomiento este [curso](https://www.edx.org/es/course/introduction-computer-science-mitx-6-00-1x-11), esta en ingles pero puedes ponerle subtitulos a los videos y es gratuito.